# Java - Read a List returned from MYSQL query with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

My Java class do a mysql query and it's result is stored in result list.

In the attached image you can see the structure data of one element of the list result.
[image]
My question is: how can I parse each element? How can I access to these values?

I don't want to use Object type.

```
String queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*),tabid FROM occurrencesnames group by tabid";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
List result = query.list();
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
String queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*),tabid FROM occurrencesnames group by tabid";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
List result = query.list();
Object[] row = (Object[]) result.get(0);
String name = (String)row[1];
```

Comment: Your answer has shown up in the low quality posts queue because there is no description of the code. In general, explaining your code adds value to your answer.